# How to store Images in react-native Android App?

Tags: android, image, react-native

I am receiving base64 ImageString through WebSocket. Now I want to store it using ImageStore. But It is specific to IOS. Is there any way to achieve similar for Android?

Comment: Do you want to store images locally for both platforms?